# wp functions.php flexslider settings

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So, I'm a novice at WordPress. I've got this in functions.php which loads the script on every page that gets the footer:

```
// flexslider custom settings       
add_action('wp_footer', 'aplace_flexslider_settings');

    function aplace_flexslider_settings() { 
?>          
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){

              $('.flexslider').flexslider();

         });            
        </script>
```

Is there a way to customized this so that its called only on the static front page? For example, can I make a custom hook that I'd add_action to and then just get_customHook on the front page? That would disassociate it with the footer, right? I'm so confused...

Comment: even if someone could point me in the right direction via the codex or something I'd be much obliged. The codex looks like a labyrinth to me right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your function in an if statement:

```
function aplace_flexslider_settings() { 
    if(is_front_page()) { ?>          
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){

              $('.flexslider').flexslider();

         });            
        </script>
<?php } } ?>
```